# python mock unittest: 'self' parameter lacking default value

Tags: python, python-mock

I am trying to test a class method that calls another class method. I have seen this question, but I think this is slightly different. I tried the answer to that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376826/python-mock-self-parameter-lacking-default-value), but it was not working. I continue to get this error:

```
AssertionError: Expected call: run(autocommit=False, parameters=None, sql='SELECT')
Actual call: run(<plugins.bigsql.hooks.bigsql_hook.BigSqlHook object at 0x10b201050>, 'SELECT', False, parameters=None)
'self' parameter lacking default value
```

Here is the code for the test:

```
import mock

from plugins.bigsql.hooks import BigSqlHook
from plugins.bigsql.operators import BigSqlOperator


@mock.patch.object(BigSqlHook, 'run', autospec=True)
def test_bigsql_hook(mock_hook_object):
    """Test BigSqlOperator connection is formed correctly."""
    operator = BigSqlOperator(task_id='test', jdbc_conn_id='sqlite_default', sql='SELECT')
    operator.execute(context={})

    mock_hook_object.assert_called_with(sql="SELECT", autocommit=False, parameters=None)
```

Here is the code for the class method I am trying to test:

```
import logging

from airflow.operators.jdbc_operator import JdbcOperator

from plugins.bigsql.hooks import BigSqlHook


class BigSqlOperator(JdbcOperator):
    """Extends py:class:`airflow.hooks.jdbc_operator.JdbcOperator` to connect to IBM BigSQL.

    Notes:
        Works the same as JdbcOperator, just uses the BigSqlHook instead
    """

    def execute(self, context):
        """Execute SQL statement on IBM BigSQL."""
        logging.info('Executing: {0}'.format(str(self.sql)))
        hook = BigSqlHook(jdbc_conn_id=self.jdbc_conn_id)
        hook.run(self.sql, self.autocommit, parameters=self.parameters)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I had to remove the `auto_spec=True` and not pass in key word arguments.

This worked:

```
import mock

from plugins.bigsql.hooks import BigSqlHook
from plugins.bigsql.operators import BigSqlOperator


@mock.patch.object(BigSqlHook, 'run')
def test_bigsql_hook(mock_hook_object):
    """Test BigSqlOperator connection is formed correctly."""
    operator = BigSqlOperator(task_id='test', jdbc_conn_id='sqlite_default', sql='SELECT')
    operator.execute(context={})

    mock_hook_object.assert_called_with("SELECT", False, parameters=None)
```